# NodeJS | Steam Market Analyzer

Tags: node.js, steam

People who deal with steam probably have heard of website like that: http://csgo.steamlytics.xyz/

For learning I though I'll try to do somewhat same API like they have, but I have one question. I have made to the part, where it's getting each item name and doing a request to Steam market history URL and grabbing data from there and putting it to the DB. There is 6844 items and I have set a timeout for each request 2 seconds, so if I did the math right it should take ~6 hours to get all items data to the database. Question is here, is there a possible way to speed up the process? Regarding to steamlytics site, they update the data every 12 hours so I don't believe that they update prices 6 hours each time. Here is my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < names.items.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(i) {
        var name = names.items[i].market_hash_name;
        scrapeItems(names.items[i].market_hash_name, function(data) {
            var total = 0;
            var price = 0;
            var average = 0;
            var count = 0;
            var data = JSON.parse(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.prices.length; i++) {
                var dataa = {
                    name: name,
                    date: data.prices[i][0],
                    price: data.prices[i][1],
                    sales: data.prices[i][2]
                };
                connection.query('INSERT INTO item_histories SET ?', dataa, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else{
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        console.log("Inserted data to DB " + name);
    }, i * 2000, i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with doing these requests is that you get rate limited really fast if you do the amount of requests you are doing. The request limit is per IP and there you have your solution. You need more IP's. Either way there are API's for Servers to change IP's but Proxies are working too.

The creator of steamlytics created a package to rotate over your proxies when doing requests. The package is called [node-rotating-proxy-manager](https://github.com/waylaidwanderer/node-rotating-proxy-manager).

Otherwise i know steamlytics is fetching market prices differently. He is using this [url](http://steamcommunity.com/market/recentcompleted) which holds all recent completed market transactions. You need to scan this 3 times per second i believe to get all prices by average. For items way above market limit (~400$) you need to use other sources like OPSkins to get good prices for items.

Comment: Thank You for the answer, but I can't understand how can he get average for all items, it shows only recent completed, it takes a way longer to get all items through that + in that JSON I can't find price(s)?

Comment: Yeah he is checking this endpoint every second 3 times. So he is checking this all the time 24/7. After some time (i believe more than 1 month) he gathered so much data that he could give accurate prices. See the [API documentation](http://csgo.steamlytics.xyz/api). After all this data is gathered he is running algorithms over the data set to get an accurate price.

Comment: Hey, but how my URL isn't better? It has prices 2015-2017 (I don't belive he started getting all the items from the start) because has as well.

Comment: Yours is probably better. We do not know. Its different from case to case (for some items yours is more accurate, for some other items the API is better). Steam is not showing all transactions in their market history is the biggest problem. So its a question of trusting steam.

What i am doing right now is combining different API's into one to get accurate prices. There are https://api.csgofast.com/sih/all, https://steamapi.io/ also to get prices (be careful with those, they all can be inaccurate).

Comment: Yeah, you are correct about that. I already found one item what is not on that API for some reason, and you can't get banned if you are spamming that API I just lately saw one thing that if you spam "too long" then for like 5 seconds appears a message that "Access Denied" and then u can continue, so probably have to do some "fail checking" for the method.

Comment: I would be careful about that because you dont know how steam will react with banning IP's or something similar. Btw. i highly suggest you to join the discord of r/steambot https://discord.gg/CytHBca . The creators of the API's are there and you can ask them questions if you want to ^^